# HTML element as square

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have task to write a game with a field that contains squares in random field location. After clicking square, it should "die"(and then spawns 0-2 new squares) and player ups his score. My framework is Bootstrap. 
The main thing - not use Canvas(squares should be simple HTML elements)
What HTML element do i can use for square element?
Maybe it is simple table where cells are squares

Comment: Probably yes. It can be every element you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `<div>` and style it with CSS. For instance,

```css
div.square
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

For all the other stuff, like dying and respawning, use JavaScript. You can position it by dynamically setting the `left` and `top` CSS property to a random value.

Comment: But i need locate some squares on one line and div is block element

Comment: Your question says you spawn in a random place on a field. I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to spawn squares in container randomly(random location). How can i use div if it is a block element? Squares can locate on one line

Comment: Or i should use table where cells are my squares?

Comment: So, it can't just be anywhere in the container, only on a certain line?

Comment: It can be anywhere inside container

Comment: so then that's block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.square {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What element should i use as a square?